# How can I use MS office 2016 by default while MS office 2010 is installed?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

I have various versions of MS office installed so I can test auto-generated documents can be opened in several versions. I want to use office 2016 as my default when I open an office document, but ever since installing office 2010 everything opens in 2010 by default.

If I try to change the default app for a file type, I only get the choice of Microsoft Excel/Word, etc. not the specific version. Similarly, if I right click an excel file, choose Open With and navigate to the excel 2016 exe file it still opens in 2010.

Any ideas how I can keep office 2010 installed but set office 2016 as my default for opening office files?

**Update:** I'm having this problem in windows 10.

Comment: I don't have two versions of office installed so I haven't tested this, but here's something to try: right-click an Office doc and choose Open With > Choose Default Program. In the next window that comes up, don't pick Word/Excel from the list of applications up top but instead click on Browse and then navigate to the 2016 folder; e.g. C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Excel.exe

Comment: Although that's for Windows 7. You didn't mention your version of Windows. If you have Windows 10, you have to do it slightly differently.

Comment: I already tried navigating to Excel.exe, this was what I meant by "if I right click an excel file, choose Open With and navigate to the excel 2016 exe file it still opens in 2010" but I perhaps didn't phrase it very well. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks for your suggestion though.